# I want to float the image into the center with having the ability of writing left and right next to it, but float: center does not even exist

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float

float: center dose not even exist
I tried a lot of methods, yet non of them worked.
I search for a solution,  and all of them were align left or right with the text on the opposite side. But there was not align center with text in both sides... So, a solution, please. Preferably writing the style in the img tag...

This is my html so far:

```
<img style="float: center; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;" src="image.png"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

So there is no float: center. However you could use float:left; on all elements. It will float left in order and if there all from a small size they will be placed next to eachother like this.

```html
<p style="float:left;">Left</p>
<img style="float:left;" src="#">
<p style="float:left;">Right</p>
```

But then a again this method is really tricky and there are much better ways to structure you code and layout. Flex-boxes for example. A bit harder to understand, but once you'll get it it's very helpfull.

```css
/*This external css is just for show*/
div{
  text-align: center; 
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is the minimum code you'll need -->
<div style="display:flex;">
  <div style="flex:1;"> <p>BlaBla</p> </div>
  <div style="flex:1;"> <img src="#"> </div>
  <div style="flex:1;"> <p>and some more blabla</p> </div>
</div>
```